# Regex.Replace not replacing properly

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string (PointName) that I need to replace any of the following characters with an empty string :/?*'[]. Below is the script I have using c#:

```
    Regex.Replace(PointName, @"\:/?*'[]", @"")
```

I tried above but getting the following message:

parsing ":/?*'[]" - Unterminated [] set.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `Regex.Replace not replacing properly` actually, the truth is, its most likely doing exactly what you told it to do. just saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Regex` object that is associated with the pattern, then use replace.

```
string pattern = @"[[\]?/\\:*']";
string replacement = " ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

You need to use an the OR operation to create the regex statement that eliminates the characters wanted to eliminate. You can not simply just list the characters.

Comment: Or `pattern=@"[[\]?/\\:*']";` (or `pattern=@"[[\]?/:*']";` since I can't tell from OP if he wants the backslash or not) also.. No need to escape the colon, single quote, or the right brace in your example.

Comment: Also: a new `Regex` object is *not* required. `Regex.Replace` works just as well. OP's issue was that their pattern was invalid due to the need to escape reserved regex characters and the alternation